# Is there a reason LOAD DATA will not accept pipe delimited files

Tags: mysql, etl

When I try to run this:

```html
LOAD DATA INFILE 'MyFile.txt'
INTO TABLE CLIMATE_DATA
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
(
 STATION_ID,
 WBAN_ID,
 DATE,
 MEAN_TEMP,
 NUM_OBSERVATIONS_TEMP,
 MEAN_DEW_POINT,
 NUM_OBSERVATIONS_DEW_POINT,
 MEAN_SEA_LEVEL_PRESSURE,
 NUM_OBSERVATIONS_SEA_LEVEL_PRESSURE,
 MEAN_STATION_PRESSURE,
 NUM_OBSERVATIONS_STATION_PRESSURE,
 MEAN_VISIBILITY,
 NUM_OBSERVATIONS_MEAN_VISIBILITY,
 MEAN_WIND_SPEED,
 NUM_OBSERVATIONS_WIND_SPEED,
 MAX_WIND_SPEED,
 MAX_WIND_GUST,
 MAX_TEMP,
 MAX_TEMP_FLAG,
 MIN_TEMP,
 MIN_TEMP_FLAG,
 TOTAL_PRECIPITATION,
 TOTAL_PRECIPITATION_FLAG,
 SNOW_DEPTH,
 WEATHER_PHENOMENON 
)
IGNORE 1 LINES;
```

I get: "Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''' at line 3"

It will work fine with ','. The syntax appears to be correct. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: i smell a data file with not properly escaped values. Example: `'1','True','Donald O' Brian'` See the `'` in the name? It breaks the whole Query cause it work like a separator `'` it should be `'1','True','Donald O\' Brian'` These situations can be ugly.

Comment: There are NO escaped values actually. It's all ints and floats. The query doesn't even get to the file yet. It breaks on the SQL validation.

Comment: check if file size exceeds max limit of import. if thats not the problem, then you must manually cut the file in parts and try to import each part separately so you will be able to  pinpoint the error. If you need more specific help, we need to see the datafile.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the *entire* `LOAD DATA` command. Also, please tell us whether this command fails instantly. Does it fail in the exact same way if you give it the name of a file you know is not present?

Comment: It fails instantly. It doesn't ever get to reading the file. There is a problem with the syntax. The file is 5 GB.

Comment: are you **sure** it doesnt get to read the file? Can you manually create a similar txt file with a line or two of data and try to import it with the very same command? (this just to investigate if big file size is the problem)

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to point out that "IGNORE 1 LINES" will need to be between your "LINES TERMINATED BY..." and table fields  "(STATION_ID, ....". 
In relation to your code:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'MyFile.txt'
INTO TABLE CLIMATE_DATA
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES <<--place ignore here
(
    STATION_ID,
    WBAN_ID,
    DATE,
    MEAN_TEMP,
    NUM_OBSERVATIONS_TEMP,
    MEAN_DEW_POINT,
    NUM_OBSERVATIONS_DEW_POINT,
    MEAN_SEA_LEVEL_PRESSURE,
    NUM_OBSERVATIONS_SEA_LEVEL_PRESSURE,
    MEAN_STATION_PRESSURE,
    NUM_OBSERVATIONS_STATION_PRESSURE,
    MEAN_VISIBILITY,
    NUM_OBSERVATIONS_MEAN_VISIBILITY,
    MEAN_WIND_SPEED,
    NUM_OBSERVATIONS_WIND_SPEED,
    MAX_WIND_SPEED,
    MAX_WIND_GUST,
    MAX_TEMP,
    MAX_TEMP_FLAG,
    MIN_TEMP,
    MIN_TEMP_FLAG,
    TOTAL_PRECIPITATION,
    TOTAL_PRECIPITATION_FLAG,
    SNOW_DEPTH,
    WEATHER_PHENOMENON 
);
```

When I run the above I get the following error:

> "ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IGNORE 1 LINES' at line 32"

**I don't think you had the complete error copied in your clip board.**

Also, you may want to try to use "LOAD DATA **LOCAL** INFILE" which you may need to use the --local-infile param when logging into the mysql prompt a good example on how to do this has been described in: [error when I import local data infile](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/55960/mysql-import-csv-file-error-13-hy000-cant-get-stat-of-path-file-csv-errcod)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone is looking to import a file using mysqlimport and has PIPE as a delimiter.

Use the command in this fashion

```
mysqlimport --ignore-lines=1  --local -u root -p seo D:\SEO.txt --fields-terminated-by="|"
```